# How do I deal with preprocessing and with unseen data in a NLP problem?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tf-idf

Suppose that I have preprocessed some text data, removed stopwords, urls and so on.

How should I structure these cleaned data in order to make them usable for a classifier like a Neural Network? Is there a preferred structure, or a rule of thumb? (Bag of words, tf-idf or anything else?) Also, can you suggest some package which will automatically do all the work in python?

Now I train the model, and things work properly.
The model performs well on test set too.

How do I have to treat unseen data?
When I decide to implement the model in a real life project it will encounter new data: do I have to store the structure (like the tf-idf structure) I used for training and apply it to these new data?
Also, let's suppose that in the training/validation/test data there was not the word "hello", so it has not a representation. A real life sentence I have to classify contains the word "hello"
How do I cope with this problem?

Thanks for all the clarifications.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings should provide most of your answers

Answer (score 0):

What you can do the make a class and inside that define the function like

1. import dataset
2. data cleaning
3. data preprocessing(BOW, TfIDf)
4. model building
5. predictions

You can follow up the code from the below like to get understanding

https://github.com/azeem110201/lifecycledatascienceproject